# Use of $.data(li, "ac_data", data[i]) from function fillList() of jquery-autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using the jquery-autocomplete plugin of Jörn Zaefferer and I can't understand the use of this line in the fillList() function:

```
$.data(li, "ac_data", data[i]);
```

Please help me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery.data](http://docs.jquery.com/Internals/jQuery.data)

each tag "li" which creates, assigns the data in "ac_data" with the value in data[i];

variable declaration data:

```
    var listItems,
        active = -1,
        data,
        term = "",
        needsInit = true,
        element,
        list;
```

assigning value to variable data:

```
    display: function(d, q) {
        init();
        data = d;
        term = q;
        fillList();
    },
```

Comment: Then it turns out that ac_data acts like a variable, am I right?  Thanks.

Comment: is as creating a property for each "li" with the name "ac_data" and the value of "data[i]"